# Class-Transformer with @Type discriminator for children that maps to parent type not working

Tags: reactjs, class-transformer

I am having this issue with a type mapping that is failing when mapping to a type that is the same as the parent, I.e container has children (abstract class type `Base`) that can be a `container` too or an `item`.

The strange thing is I have exactly the same code in another project (using a different front end framework) and it's working fine.
I am not sure if there's something about CRA project that is causing the issue but nothing I have tried has allowed me to get past this issue.

https://github.com/4imble/class-transformer-recursion-issue

Here is a minimal project that demonstrates the error:
`ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Container' before initialization at ./src/domain/container.ts (container.ts:12:1)`

```
import Base from "./base";
import Item from "./item";
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';

export default class Container extends Base
{
    @Type(() => Base, {
        discriminator: {
            property: "type",
            subTypes: [
                { value: Item, name: "item" },
                { value: Container, name: "container" }
            ]
        }
    })
    children: Array<Item | Container> = []
}
```

https://github.com/4imble/class-transformer-recursion-issue/blob/3ca9dbee794cb900a6753da70e485e1a3472f14f/src/domain/container.ts

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, I gave up, re created my project using Vite instead of CRA and it's working now. Most likely an issue with Webpack as I suspected.